# ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut - Android Native app

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-anr-dialog

In an native cpp application compiled for Android I am getting ANR error with the cause keyDispatchingTimedOut.It only happens sometimes when the app switches from native activity to java activity.

Nothing in the error report really stands out. Most of the threads just sit in a loop waiting for input. I cant disclose any code but the code at 58b505 is from android_native_app_glue library.

I have attached the ANR error report: [full ANR on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/fseaumpK)

```
   "main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
     | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x741e33c0 self=0xab684ea8
     | sysTid=29202 nice=-1 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf778fb34
     | state=S schedstat=( 962236509 24407600 624 ) utm=84 stm=12 core=4 HZ=100
     | stack=0xff56e000-0xff570000 stackSize=8MB
     | held mutexes=
     native: pc 0000000000042c9c  /system/lib/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+20)
     native: pc 00000000000195cf  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_pwait+26)
     native: pc 00000000000195dd  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+6)
     native: pc 0000000000012d8b  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+102)
     native: pc 0000000000013007  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+130)
     native: pc 00000000000836fd  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+22)
     native: pc 000000000000055d  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+96)
     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)
     at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:323)
     at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5438)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:738)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:628)

"Thread-295" prio=6 tid=17 Native
     | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c630a0 self=0xabdbcd60
     | sysTid=29269 nice=-1 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xdabfd930
     | state=S schedstat=( 15667236 2344530 115 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=6 HZ=100
     | stack=0xdab01000-0xdab03000 stackSize=1014KB
     | held mutexes=
     native: pc 0000000000016908  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
     native: pc 000000000004167b  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL33__pthread_cond_timedwait_relativeP23pthread_cond_internal_tP15pthread_mutex_tPK8timespec+56)
     native: pc 000000000058b505  /data/app/com.package-1/lib/arm/libgame.so (???)
     native: pc 000000000058b2ed  /data/app/com.package-1/lib/arm/libgame.so (???)
     native: pc 00000000005ac4c7  /data/app/com.package-1/lib/arm/libgame.so (???)
     native: pc 000000000004185b  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
     native: pc 00000000000192a5  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
```